# Invalid AdvertisedId id bytes length

Tags: google-beacon-platform, proximityapi

I am trying to register my beacon on OAuth2.0 Playground. When I am trying to register my beacon, it gives me following error:

```
{   "error": {
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
"message": "Invalid AdvertisedId id bytes length", 
"code": 400   } 
}
```

I am sending a `POST` request to `https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons:register` with following `application/json` body:

```
 {
  "advertisedId": {
    "type": "EDDYSTONE",
    "id": "ZWRkMWViXWFjMDRlNWRlZmEwNTdkMGU3ZDAwMmQ4YmM="
  },
  "status": "ACTIVE",
}
```

I am calculating `advertiseID` of beacon by this:

`InstanceID`: `e61bdd5c2a9a`

`Namespace:` `edd1ebfac04e5defa017`

I am creating the `advertiseId` by this method:

**[1]** Concatenate `Namespace+Instance`. => `edd1ebfac04e5defa017e61bdd5c2a9a`

**[2]** Convert it to byte stream using following code:

`byte[] message = "edd1ebfac04e5defa017e61bdd5c2a9a".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

**[3]** Then convert it to `Base64` using following code:

`String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(message);`

Now `encoded` is our `advertisedId` which is `ZWRkMWViXWFjMDRlNWRlZmEwNTdkMGU3ZDAwMmQ4YmM=`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonably common problem with converting between the hex values for the beacon ID and the actual underlying binary values for these.

The base64 string `"ZWRkMWViXWFjMDRlNWRlZmEwNTdkMGU3ZDAwMmQ4YmM="` is actually the base64 encoding of the **text** hex string `"edd1ebfac04e5defa017e61bdd5c2a9a"`. But what you really need to do is base64 encode the **binary** values underlying this hex string.

In Node.jS, for example:

```
var b = Buffer("edd1ebfac04e5defa017e61bdd5c2a9a", "hex");
b.length;
> 16 bytes    // The 32 char string above represents 16 bytes!

b.toString("base64");
> '7dHr+sBOXe+gF+Yb3Vwqmg=='
b.toString("base64").length;
> 24
```

So, as you can see, you should be getting a base64 string that's roughly 24 bytes in length.

So, your conversion function should be something along the following lines:

```
String convertHexBeaconIDToAdvertisementID(String hex) {
    byte[] bytes = ByteString.decodeHex(hex).toByteArray();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone needs a full working example in java :),

```
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Eddystone{

    public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    }

    public static String convertHexBeaconIDToAdvertisementID(String hex) {
        byte[] encoded = toByteArray(hex);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encoded);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Base64 Eddystone AdvertisementID: " + 
            convertHexBeaconIDToAdvertisementID("edd1ebfac04e5defa017e61bdd5c2a9a"));
    }
}
```